# How can I have manytomany relation among three model classes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserType1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,parent_link=True,primary_key=True)

class UserType2(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,parent_link=True,primary_key=True)

class UserType3(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,parent_link=True,primary_key=True)
```

Each of three types of users has its own unique fields.
I want to let users be able to follow any user he/she wants. 
How can I do a manytomany among three different model classes? 
Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe an abstract model between Model.auth.User and the three types of users?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `ManyToManyField` in each model point to `User`

```
class UserType1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True,primary_key=True)
    followed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='followers')
```

Do the same with other models. Better yet, create an [abstract base class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for the common fields in your models. This will save you time and trouble of typing common fields again and again.